# Converting mass density to point mass approximation on a grid

Tags: multigrid, grid, particle, acceleration

In an nbody gravity simulation, instead of doing exact(all-pair brute force) solution, I added masses of each body into cells of a 3D grid(each cell is just a float value having a mass value). Then smoothed the grid using a stencil. Now I'm trying to get an approximation of point masses for point masses, from grid. I have already tried directly doing body-cell interaction(similar to body-body but using smoothed mass of cell and center position of cell) but this selects originally non-mass containing cells as if they are attracting and leads to high errors.

What could be the most precise(or logical) way to do one of below options:

- a unit mass at an approximated position
- an approximated mass at a unit distance and angle
- approximation of both mass and distance

so that long-range component of total force properly acts same as all-pair brute-force version(long-range part of it)?

Or, what could be a proper way other than upper options? Can I use derivate of mass density(by neighboring cells) for these?

For now I'm calculating only an RMS error between all pair(but only long range part) version and this center-of-cell with smoothed mass (only with closest neighbor cells after long range distance(which equals 2*cell size)) to check how close the simulation is to all-pair version.

I'm doing this grid smoothing because I want to learn multigrid acceleration for nbody. To learn it step by step (and to do a performance comparison against later), only using a single grid with simple smoothing(16x16x16 cubes(as grid size) and 16 smoothing steps with 26 closest neighbor cells(using successive over relaxation ).

Initially both versions start in a cube volume.(Total particles are just 3072)

[image]

then at each timestep, rms of error of all body positions between two versions is calculated.

[image]

Addition of point masses to cells are done very simply as

```
atomic_add(closest_cell_to_current_particle,all_of_current_particle_mass);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are inventing [Barnes-Hut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation)-type algorithm, which is a fundamental accelerated algorithm for n-body simulations. It follows a similar logic: you combine masses on a grid. But, it is done in a more elaborate fashion:

- when particles are close, you still use direct calculations (no combination), otherwise, you would lose accuracy.
- multipole expansions (center of mass) are used on an octree (in 3D) to accelerate distant interactions.

Since there are many more distant interactions when you handle your particles in a tree-fashion, this leads to the complexity reduction: $\mathcal O(N\log N)$ vs $\mathcal O(N^2)$ for direct computation.